# Check entered password if its correct, match with sha256 pw in PHP

Tags: php

I have a password;

```
828b8f98ec52c750bf018c92951c6e40ae3976e74c888e42ff55ff22403932af
```

I am using Kohana 3 for my Auth login normally.

now i need to make a separate script, where a client can enter his password only and then it should check if the password it correct.

So what im dealing with is:

```
$real_pwd = '828b8f98ec52c750bf018c92951c6e40ae3976e74c888e42ff55ff22403932af';
$entered_pwd = $_GET['pwd']; // test purposes i know its vuln for sql injection ...

if ( $real_pwd == crypt($entered_pwd) ) { echo "OK"; }
```

This is not working ofcourse, crypt() is something i tried, but i dont know what to use?

If it was a sha1 pw i could use sha1 for the entered_pwd, but what with sha256?

Comment: Is that the actual password, or its hash? I'd hate to have to live your organization's PW policy if that's the plaintext PW...

Comment: I would recommend to read [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords

Comment: How could it be vulnerable for SQL injects if you're not using the $entered_pwd inside a query? (Hashing transforms any string into a hex character string so the can be no SQL injection code in the hashed string).

Comment: I am just not part of the code. No its not the actual pw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use hash() http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php

However I recommend you to have a look at bcrypt and use it for hashing password. Have a look here [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

Here's some other resources you *might* find useful:
[Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

[Fundamental difference between Hashing and Encryption algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms/4948393#4948393)